# Configure folder as application root path

Tags: asp.net, iis, root

I have the following domain "http://www.myapps.com" which contains two web applications.
In IIS 7.5 i have them configured this way:

```
MYAPPS (Website - http://www.myapps.com)
|
|-------MyAppOne (Application - Accessible by http://www.myapps.com)
|
|-------MyAppTwo (Application - Accessible by http://www.myapps.com/apptwo)
```

Problem:

In MyAppTwo website, when i click for example in the hyperlink with the path "/Default.aspx", i'm redirected to http://www.myapps.com/Default.aspx .

How can i configure IIS to redirect instead to http://www.myapps.com/apptwo/Default.aspx?

Thanks!

Comment: What does "...tries to access the root path..." mean? How can application "access a root path"?

Comment: The web applications, are in fact to asp.net web apps.
When i say "tries to access the root path" i mean when the application tries to access a webpage in the root folder where it's stored for example /Default.aspx. I hope you can now understand now. Thanks.